# Flutter Web Desktop view for mobile devices | Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'am developing a website using Flutter. It runs fine in desktop but when i open that website in mobile browser it is zoomed too much and contents are not showing properly. But in mobile browser when i switch its view to desktop it shows correctly. So i want to make my website to show as desktop view in mobile phone browser as default. Is there any solution to view my webpage as desktop view as default in mobile browsers.

Comment: Could you share a small piece of code to reproduce. The right approach is to layout your widget according to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try using a library like responsive framework: https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework

it worked for me:

```
ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
          AppFrame(child: child!),
          defaultScale: isDisplayScaled(context),
        )
```

Comment: `bool isDisplayPortrait(BuildContext context) =>
    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

bool isDisplayScaled(BuildContext context) =>
    (MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio > 1.0 &&
        isDisplayPortrait(context));`